# SQL search changed from like to equals not working

Tags: php, sql, where-clause, sql-like, addslashes

php/sql newbie.
Trying to change a LIKE name search into an exact search. Fails to find any records even when use search values that I know are in the table.

Original code:

```
 $sch = "SELECT record_key, surname, given_names, birth_date, death_date, age
               FROM records
               WHERE surname LIKE '".addslashes($name)."%';
    $result = mysql_query($sch);
```

New code:

```
 $sch = "SELECT record_key, surname, given_names, birth_date, death_date, age
               FROM records
               WHERE surname = '".addslashes($name)."%';
    $result = mysql_query($sch);
```

I have tried everything I can think of, including:

```
 WHERE surname = 'addslashes($name)';
```

(I wasn't sure of the reason for the " each end or the %)

The only way I can get it to work is if I scrap the addslashes and just use:
               WHERE surname = '$name';

which I understand is vulnerable to injection.

Comment: You can't use `=`along with the `%` wildcard.

Comment: Don't use the mysql_* functions. They are deprecated as of PHP 5.5. And seriously read up on SQL injection, it might save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: Headaches and hacking :)

Comment: try `mysql_real_escape_string($name)`, but you should really move to `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 $sch = "SELECT record_key, surname, given_names, birth_date, death_date, age
               FROM records
               WHERE surname = '".addslashes($name)."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sch);
```

without the `%`.

`%` is a wildcard in `LIKE` patterns, but is a regular character in `=` ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. It now seems to be working fine. I am sure that I previously deleted everything unnecessary including the %, but obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

The trailing `%` that you have in your `LIKE` clause is present in your exact search.  The `%` only has meaning when using `LIKE`, so it is looking for an exact match of whatever you're passing, but with a `%` on the end.

`LIKE 'criteria%'` will find anything that BEGINS with `criteria`

`= 'criteria%'` will match that literal *exactly*, including the %.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%` with `LIKE` Clause, just change your code like below...

```
$sch = "SELECT record_key, surname, given_names, birth_date, death_date, age
               FROM records
               WHERE surname = '".addslashes($name)."';
    $result = mysql_query($sch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to properly end query string with double quotes:

```
$sch = "SELECT record_key, surname, given_names, birth_date, death_date, age
 FROM records
 WHERE surname LIKE '".addslashes($name)."%'";
```